# Can't refresh selectpicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I'm trying to append some options on the Silvio Moreto's Bootstrap select picker.

When I try to update it after the append, jquery throws this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).selectpicker is not a function
```

I've read around that It's because select picker is not fully initialized, but if I go to my heading partial, the select picker js and css is included way before the function that tries to update it.

I've also read that this should be done inside a `$(function(){});` block. But since the file that is performing the operation is a plain functions file that is called inside a `$(function(){});` block the problem shouldn't present.

## This is my heading file:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>GMS</title>

<!-- Fonts -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-XdYbMnZ/QjLh6iI4ogqCTaIjrFk87ip+ekIjefZch0Y+PvJ8CDYtEs1ipDmPorQ+" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700">

<!-- Styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
{{-- <link href="{{ elixir('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"> --}}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url('css/general.css')}}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url('css/modal.css')}}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url('css/status_page.css')}}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url('css/dropdowns.css')}}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url('css/animator.css')}}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<!-- Jquery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap select with live src -->
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<!-- AngularJS -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>


<!--
|-----------------------------------
|   Custom CSS
|-----------------------------------
-->
@section('css')@show


<!--
|-----------------------------------
|   Custom JS
|-----------------------------------
-->
<script src="{{url('js/general.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{url('js/functions/functions.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{url('js/functions/animator.js')}}"></script>

<script src="{{url('js/app/gms.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{url('js/app/controllers/auth_controller.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{url('js/app/controllers/redirect_controller.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{url('js/app/controllers/changelog_controller.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{url('js/app/factories/changelog_factory.js')}}"></script>
@section('js')@show
```

## This is the function that performs the changes in the select:

```
function fillContracts(contracts) {
    for(var i = 0; i < contracts.length; i++)
    {
        console.log('Iterating');
        console.log('Contract ID: ' + contracts[i].id);
        console.log('Contract TITLE: ' + contracts[i].titolo);
        $('#selectpicker').html('<option>Test1</option><option>Test2</option>').selectpicker('refresh');
    }
    console.log('Done');
}
```

The file containing this function is injected in the heading using Blade. The Laravel's template engine. When I check the page source, it's correctly included **after** the select picker.

If it might help, the data that I try to append comes from a AJAX call. But I can't figure out what's wrong...

Thanks for any help!

## Update

I'm still trying to figure out what's wrong. The problem is that I keep getting the error when I try to use the selectpicker plugin. But I can't understand what's missing...

#### Bootstrap CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

#### Jquery:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

#### Bootstrap-select.min.css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
```

#### And the bootstrap-select.min.js:

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You don't appear to have included the selectPicker plugin JS file in the page

Comment: @Rory McCrossan But on the official site there's nothing about that... Where can I find this file?

Comment: https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

Comment: I'm still getting the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

how i was able to solve it is by putting 
**Bootsrap select.js as the last script inclusion**

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

**if it continues to give you issue.**
avoid selectpicker(refresh) and populate select box by javascript means

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("selectboxID").innerHTML = '<option>Test1</option><option>Test2</option>';
</script>

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```